# How to suppress warnings from external packages?

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack, hpack

My stack build shows warning from external packages, like:

```
happy               > /tmp/stack-d6caed253e9f21bf/happy-1.20.0/src/ProduceGLRCode.lhs:224:12: warning: [-Wincomplete-uni-patterns] 
176happy               >     Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
```

There's not much I can do about external code, and I don't want to see these warnings. However, I still want to build my project strictly with GHC options `-Wall -Werror.`

Is there a way to suppress the warnings from external packages? I'm using stack with hpack. Note that **the solution has to work from command line**, since updating stack.yaml is not possible due to a large number of projects involved.

**Things I've tried:**

- In `stack.yaml`:

```
ghc-options:
    "$targets": -Wall -Werror
    "$everything": -w
```

Combined with `--verbosity warn` from command line, this works, but I couldn't find a way to specify the above `ghc-options` from the command line.

- In `stack.yaml`:

```
apply-ghc-options: targets
```

This doesn't work, warning from external packages are still visible. Besides, I couldn't find a way to specify the above `apply-ghc-options` from the command line.

P.S: Opened a [ticket](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/6048) on GitHub after getting no answer here.

Comment: A relevant option seems to be `ghc-options`: https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#ghc-options